# Establish ConnectionString using a list as a source

Tags: database-connection

I have a field named "classes". I need to fetch data from the database and bind it to the classes field.

But the requirement is, instead of using connection string directly I need to store the connection string in the SharePoint list and then need to call it in the place of connection string.

ex: suppose title and connection are two fields in a SharePoint list. Based on the title field I need to fetch the connection string in connection column and bind it as a connection string.

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 1):

For connecting fields to external data you can best use Business Connectivity Services (BCS). This way you can store your connection in a secure and central place in Cental Admin.

With **Business Connectivity Services**, you can use SharePoint and Office clients as interfaces into data that doesn’t live in SharePoint 2013 itself.

For example, this external data may be in a database and it is accessed by using the out-of-the-box Business Connectivity Services connector for that database. Business Connectivity Services can also connect to data that is available through a web service, or data that is published as an OData source or many other types of external data

For more informatie about BCS see [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the connection string in a list, I would suggest storing it in the Secure Store service application. The Secure Store will store the connection in an encrypted state in the database. Your code can then use the Secure Store API to retrieve the connection string.